# Python: Convert unicode string to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: python, datetime, converters

I have a unicode string for example **u'Mar232012'**. I want to convert it to the format MM/DD/YYYY using python in the post efficient and reliable manner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.strptime(u'Mar232012', '%b%d%Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

prints `'03/23/2012'`

Comment: @_eumiro That is still a string, isn't it? Could those dates be sorted?